# What's the root of a Hakyll site?

Tags: haskell, static-site, hakyll

I see the create function takes a list of Identifiers.

```
ghci    λ> :t create
create :: [Identifier] -> Rules () -> Rules ()
```

What list of identifier should I use to match the root of the site?  Eg, I just want to make a single html page that appears on "www.example.com" without "/posts" or "/archives" or any other domain parts.

I've tried a few:

```
create "/" $ do
    route   idRoute
    compile $ pandocCompiler
        >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" defaultContext
        >>= relativizeUrls
```

and

```
create "/*" $ do
    route   idRoute
    compile $ pandocCompiler
        >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" defaultContext
        >>= relativizeUrls
```

and

```
create "." $ do
    route   idRoute
    compile $ pandocCompiler
        >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" defaultContext
        >>= relativizeUrls
```

and

```
create "./" $ do
    route   idRoute
    compile $ pandocCompiler
        >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" defaultContext
        >>= relativizeUrls
```

and

```
create "/." $ do
    route   idRoute
    compile $ pandocCompiler
        >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" defaultContext
        >>= relativizeUrls
```

and

```
create "" $ do
    route   idRoute
    compile $ pandocCompiler
        >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" defaultContext
        >>= relativizeUrls
```

and

```
create Nothing $ do
    route   idRoute
    compile $ pandocCompiler
        >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" defaultContext
        >>= relativizeUrls
```

I get errors like:

```
site.hs:24:12: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Identifier’ with ‘Char’
        arising from the literal ‘""’
    • In the first argument of ‘create’, namely ‘""’
      In the expression: create ""
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        create ""
        $ do { route idRoute;
               compile
               $ pandocCompiler
                 >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" defaultContext
                 >>= relativizeUrls }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Loaded GHCi configuration from /tmp/ghci29841/ghci-script
```

I can't say `:i Identifier` or [reading documentation](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/reference/Hakyll-Core-Identifier.html#t:Identifier) or [reading the source code](https://github.com/jaspervdj/hakyll/blob/67ecff7ad383640bc73d64edc2506c7cc648a134/lib/Hakyll/Core/Identifier.hs) makes this any clearer for me:

```
ghci    λ> :i Identifier
data Identifier
  = Hakyll.Core.Identifier.Identifier {identifierVersion :: Maybe
                                                              String,
                                       Hakyll.Core.Identifier.identifierPath :: String}
    -- Defined in ‘Hakyll.Core.Identifier’
instance Eq Identifier -- Defined in ‘Hakyll.Core.Identifier’
instance Ord Identifier -- Defined in ‘Hakyll.Core.Identifier’
instance Show Identifier -- Defined in ‘Hakyll.Core.Identifier’
```

What magic incantation should I use to create html that will appear "/", and how should I have investigated this better to make it less mysterious?

Comment: It depends on the way your server is configured. Typically `www.example.com/index.html` will be the landing page when someone tries to visit `www.example.com`. See for instance [this line](https://github.com/gallais/gallais.github.io/blob/source/src/site.hs#L68).

Comment: Have you tried `fromFilePath "./"`?

Comment: @gallais, as far as I can tell, using index.html produces a default file server that does not seem to respect any of the templates or content I provided.

Comment: @arrowd,     • Couldn't match expected type ‘Rules () -> Rules a0’
                  with actual type ‘Rules ()’

Comment: Check parentheses: `create (fromFilePath "./") $ do`.

Comment: • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Identifier]’
                  with actual type ‘Identifier’
    • In the first argument of ‘create’, namely ‘(fromFilePath "./")’
      In the expression: create (fromFilePath "./")

Replacing with

    create [(fromFilePath "./")] $ do

No error, but can't rebuild:   [ERROR] Hakyll.Core.Compiler.cached: You are trying to (perhaps indirectly) use `cached` on a non-existing resource: there is no file backing .

Comment: It kind of blows my mind this doesn't have a trivial answer that works with minimal configuration. This is "hello world" for Hakyll.

Answer (score 0):

The `create` function requires a list of `Identifiers`.  For the case of a single element, just surround it with brackets (`[]`). And `Identifier` is a member of the `IsString` class so assuming you have enabled `-XOverloadedStrings` you can build one with just a regular quoted string literal (`"index.html"`).

So to create a file that is served at the root you would write:

```
create ["index.html"] $ do
route   idRoute
compile $ pandocCompiler
    >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" defaultContext
    >>= relativizeUrls
```

---

Reminder when a path is requested without an explicit file name (e.g. `http://www.example.com/`) the contents of the file `index.html` are returned (Unless the server is configured in some other way, but this is the standard.)

Comment: I have similar, trying to use markdown:
``    create ["index.md"] $ do
      route (setExtension "html")
      compile $ pandocCompiler
        >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" defaultContext
        >>= relativizeUrls
``
I get this error when I 
``stack build``
```
  [ERROR] Hakyll.Core.Compiler.Require.load: templates/default.html (snapshot _final) was not found in the cache, the cache might be corrupted or the item you are referring to might not exist
```