# Hakyll clean and build still has caching error

Tags: haskell, hakyll

I execute the following:

```
$ stack exec site clean
Removing _site...
Removing _cache...
Removing _cache/tmp...
```

And then:

```
$ stack exec site build
Initialising...
  Creating store...
  Creating provider...
  Running rules...
Checking for out-of-date items
Compiling
  updated css/default.css
  updated images/haskell-logo.png
  [ERROR] Hakyll.Core.Compiler.cached: You are trying to (perhaps indirectly) use `cached` on a non-existing resource: there is no file backing index.html
```

How can I truly clean my hakyll site such that it builds?

(More code here: [What's the root of a Hakyll site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46356263/whats-the-root-of-a-hakyll-site) )

Comment: I guess you have deleted the index.html could you list the directory contents and your main.hs

Comment: I have an index.md, which appears in my root.  I'm expecting 
    create ["index.md"] $ do
      route (setExtension "html")
      compile $ pandocCompiler

to compile the index.md into index.html from the description here: https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/03-rules-routes-compilers.html